# putty terminal cursor buggy on debian-wheezy

Tags: terminal, putty, debian-wheezy

since my vagrant box changed from squeeze to wheezy my cursor on the terminal is kind of buggy.

for example when i try to type this command:

```
vagrant@portal-vagrant:/$ ls -l
```

it ends like this:

```
ls -l t@portal-vagrant:~$
```

as the cursor is before the prefix and just overrides it , it still works fine but it is kind of annoying. I tried various options in the putty settings put nothing helped. Any kind of help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
output from echo $PS1

```
echo $PS1ortal-vagrant:~$
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[1;35m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$
```

**UPDATE 2**
funny fact, when use the output of echo $PS1 and assign it back to it, it works just fine -.-

Comment: So you screwed up. Good to know.

Comment: @vonbrand how so? are u assuming that i wrote the content of PS1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `PS1` which is what [controls the prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) and ultimately the cursor position.

Comment: thx for the direction! any chance you could take a look at the PS1 output and point out what could cause the problem?

Comment: @braunbaer: I can't tell because I have no idea what the outcome of the debian_chroot or __git_ps1 expansions will be. Time to roll up your sleeves and debug it yourself.

Comment: @lain on it (- :